# Why is wireless slow with Atheros AR9285?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, hardware

I know there are many posts like this, however none of the fixes I have found have worked.

I had the issue on 11.04, and after having no luck fixing it decided to try 12.04 however this has not fixed the problem. I'm using a Lenovo IdeaPad, the network card is a Atheros Communications AR9285.

edit add outputs:

```
sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"NETGEAR-PLOW"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: E0:91:F5:7D:1B:BA   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:77  Invalid misc:63   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:30a1]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
--
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:392e]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Thanks

Comment: You should add the usual outputs for troubleshooting a wireless problem to the question. As is, the question is rather vague.

Comment: What would these be? (I'm new to ubuntu/linux), The speed is just throttled to 1.5Mbits, when I should be getting 12Mbits, which I get with a cable.

Comment: These two should be a good start: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2`, `sudo iwconfig`. Please add the outputs to the question, or post them to pastebin.com.

Comment: I've added iwconfig, but lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 just returnedUsage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.

Comment: I am sorry, it should have been `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`.

Comment: Thanks, try [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1877120&highlight=AR9285), posts 4 and 6.

Comment: That's not fixed it :(

Comment: I found a fix, will post the link once I find it again, was to do with using Synaptic Package Manager

Answer (score 1):

I found this to work!

http://www.jrhenkelmann.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=34

The tick box was not listed as "Pre-Released updates" but all boxes were ticked on the updates tab

Comment: Fix worked temporarily but now is back to slow speeds

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.